# Complex Filter design using Matlab's FDAtool

Tags: matlab, filters, discrete-signals

What functions does matlab's FDAtool use to design filters from pole zero placement?

Functions such as zp2sos require the the poles and zeros are either real or complex conjugates, FDAtool does not have these constraints and so can design complex filters.

Is there then a function that given zeros and poles that are not complex conjugates will return the coefficients for a sos iir filter?

Comment: If you know a filter's poles and zeros, you can state its transfer function (and therefore coefficients) directly (up to a constant gain factor). Remember that the zeros are the roots of the transfer function's numerator and the poles are the roots of its denominator.